# What's the proper way to save percentage value from flat file to database table without infinite floating values?

Tags: c#, sql-server

When importing percentage value from flat file to the database.   Say the percentage value (from flat file) is "91.92" as a string.  This value is assigned to c# "float" variable which is then saved to the database table as "float" column.

The issue I have is the string value was "91.92" and the database data end up as "91.9199981689453".   I do not want rounding or infinite values (or exponent values).

```
string ftpDataInterestRate = "91.92";  //This is from FTP file...  (Can't write ftp script here)...
float dataInterestRate = float.parse(ftpDataInterestRate);  //This is assigning the value to variable from ftp file for file reader components.

sql = " INSERT INTO Foo1 ";
sql += " (InterestRate) ";
sql += " VALUES ";
sql += " @InterestRate ";

dbCommand.CommentText = sql;
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValues("@InterestRate", dataInterestRate);
dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


[MS-SQL Table]
   [InterestRate] [float] NOT NULL
```

Is there an easier way to have the database show the values as "91.92"?  Also, if the value is "83.2" then save it as "83.2".  Also if the value is "76" then save it as "76".

Thanks..

Comment: Maybe store it as a decimal? I know in C#, Decimal is more accurate and just as precise. I think it'll work the same way in SQL Server.

Comment: @Corey I don't understand - how would using decimal lose accuracy? We seemed to agree on that point. How was I conflicting with your initial comment?

Comment: I had misread your comment thinking you meant to move to an int. I was tired yesterday. Forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a decimal. Floats and doubles are always approximations, which I guess you don't really want.

Comment: floats and doubles are not *always* approximations. Values like 1/2 and 3/16 can be stored exactly in a float (the denominator is a power of two).